# How to a split string based on amount of characters in PHP?

Tags: php, string, split

How do you split a string based on the number of letter characters and/or the number of numbers so that they are separate strings?

Hopefully this makes sense. Thanks for any help (:

For example:
The user inputs:

1. Henry, Smith ID: 123456

I would like to sort the user input into separate strings with the result of:

```
$name = 'Henry, Smith';
$ID = '123456';
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: >>> "Hopefully this makes sense". Not massively :) Show us an input and desired output. Do you want an array out of this?

Comment: can you show a relevant example !! Of what do you want exactly

Comment: Example added, sorry about that.

Comment: Will it always have `ID:` in between the name and the ID?

Comment: No, the user may input it like: 123456 Henry, Smith

Comment: So what's the criteria, then? It's a name and an ID, in any old format? That will be rather difficult to extract.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to match only numbers and everything but numbers.

```
$number = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $str);
$name = preg_replace("/[0-9]/", '', $str);
```

Note, for the `name`, this will return `Henry, Smith ID:` from your question's example. This just takes the numbers out... it doesn't know "ID:" isn't part of a person's name.

Explanation of the caret (`^`):

Inside the brackets it means match everything NOT in the brackets. So `[^0-9]` matches everything but numbers. In this example, it'll replace everything that isn't a number with a blank (second parameter). For the `$name`, we do the opposite. We replace everything that IS a number with a blank to just get the non-digit characters.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) for more info on regex.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What does ^ do in ("/[^0-9]/",?

Comment: It means everything except the stuff in the brackets. I've updated my answer with an explanation.

Comment: Thanks! What if the user input is'1. Henry, Smith ID:123456 Class:Math 2. John, Doe ID:123123 Class: English' Would regex still work?

Comment: @sachleen: That must be the most useful link I have seen in a while. Thanks for this!

Comment: @henrymb67 it can.. you just have to have a set format for the input. If you have a specific format, you can write something to parse it.

Comment: @AlexBelanger Then you'll also like [regexpal](http://www.regexpal.com/) which lets you test your expressions.